# SQL concatenate two smaller datatypes into one larger datatype

Tags: sql-server, binary

How can I essentially concatenate two smaller datatypes into one larger datatype?

TinyInt(1) = 17 = 0001 0001

TinyInt(2) = 5 =  0000 0101

New SmallInt = TinyInt(1) + TinyInt(2) = 4357 = 0001 0001 0000 0101

I am trying to do this on MSSQL Server 2008 via a stored procedure. The larger value will then be stored in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bit shift using the POWER function and then do a bitwise OR (|).

```
declare @x tinyint
declare @y tinyint

set @x = 17
set @y = 5

declare @z smallint
set @z = @x * power(2, 8) | @y
select @z
```

Comment: So with the power function I can use this for larger int types by using:  2^(bit length of larger type)?

Comment: @JosephMichael Right.  Multiplying by 2^8 (= 256) is the same as shifting left 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can pack them together by multiplying the first value out of the range of the second value.

```
v1 * 256 + v2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `varbinary` solution for you. Assuming `v1` and `v2` are `tinyint`, you could do this:

```
CAST(CAST(v1 AS varbinary(1)) + CAST(v2 AS varbinary(1)) AS smallint)
```

This method directly matches your train of thought but is certainly less elegantly looking than the purely mathematical solution [suggested by shawnt00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29085352/297408).